# In the Counter module the Visitors "This Year" count is decreasing. How can I get it to increase instead?

Tags: 8

The Visitors "This Year" count decreases in number in the D8 Counter module while the "Hits" and "Visits" increase as normal. For example, one afternoon the "This Year" count was 329,546. The next morning it was 328,149. The third day is was 327,138. The "Visits" and "Hits" only increase on the average of 150 per week. The "This Year" is decreasing more than a thousand by the day(????) What's going on? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Probably the module is counting the last 364 days. For example, yesterday, the module counted from 2018/07/03 until 2019/07/02. And today, it has counted from 2018/07/04 until 2019/07/03. Could you add a link in the question about the module in Drupal respository that you are using ?

Comment: The link to the module or the website using the module? The link to the module is https://www.drupal.org/project/counter.

Answer (score 1):

I've checked the module and i can confirm that the behaviour of the module is like previously i explained in comments. So, it is not a problem related to a module. It's a problem related to marketing analysis. Probably the "Visits" and "Hits" are absolute values ( they are always increasing ). On the other hand, the "This Year" value is a calculated value for 365 last days.

At this time last year, you had lots of visitors.